# Frequency of Characters in visual c# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a program in visual c# windows form application.
I need to find out the number of characters in a text box and display each characters' frequency in a list box.  I have the following code:

```
private void btnCheckFrequency_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstFreqMeter.Items.Clear();

    string str;
    int c = 1;
    int strlen;

    str = txtString.Text;

    strlen = txtString.TextLength;

    int[] counter = new int[strlen];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strlen; j++)
        {
            if (str[i] == str[j])
            {
                c += 1;

            }
        }
        counter[i] = c;
        c = 1;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < counter.Length; k++)
    {
        lstFreqMeter.Items.Add(counter[k]);
    }
}
```

In this code when I click the "Check Frequency" button the program gives, as output, the frequency of each character and **repeated characters, and also spaces** which we do not want.

Comment: Try something like `txtString.Text.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { chara = x.Key, frequency = x.Count() })`..

Answer (score 2):

3 loops to accomplish this is where you are going wrong.  I think you are trying to make it too complicated.

Its frowned upon to give answers to homework questions, but some hints as to direction should help.

- Declare a `Dictionary<char, int>`
- Make only one loop.  For each char in your string.
- Inside the loop, populate a `Dictionary<char, int>` with your results.
- If the char exists in the dictionary, set the int to int++, if not, add the char to the dictionary with int of 1.
- Outside the loop, AddRange to your lstFreqMeter.Items.

Comment: Isnt it your homework?  How would me giving you the code help you become a better programmer?  As it is, I've practically pseudo coded it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of chars in a string by using `Count` on the `string`.

Getting the frequency of each char you can iterate through the string and increment an integer. A dictionary (key/value list) would be a great datatype to hold this data.

```
    const string textString = "aaabbbcccaaattteeevvvooo";
    var numberOfChars = textString.Count();

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();
    foreach (var letter in textString)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(letter))
            dictionary[letter]++;
        else
            dictionary[letter] = 1;
    }
```

The Dictionary will contain a key (the char) and a value (the count).

Comment: You forgot to `Dictionary.Add(K, V)` so this will result in a runtime exception

Comment: I have just run this in .net 4.5. It should be good. At which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: @Charleh The indexer's setter of a dictionary will add an item if it doesn't exist, and replaces it if it does.  This answer is correct as it stands.

Comment: Really? I thought the setter blew up without add - maybe I'm mixed up with getter then (think I'm getting mixed up with trying to read a key that doesn't exist)! Oh well, I retract the previous! Learned something today

Comment: Thank you for your answer. .. . could you please help me How to add all the character's frequencies in a list box............lstFreqMeter.Items.Add(?)

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a dictionary of the matched characters and increment each character count as it is matched.

```
Dictionary<char, int> count = new Dictionary<char,int>();
string str = textString.Text;
int len = str.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i ++)
{
   if (str[i] == ' ') continue;
   if (count.ContainsKey(str[i]))
   {
      count[str[i]] += 1;
   } else {
      count.Add(str[i], 1);
   }
}

foreach(char key in count.Keys)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", key, count[key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply....When i type a string "kkhank" it shows the output:     k=1, h=1,a=1,n=1.............. instead of showing k=3

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 var letters = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(i => (char)i);
 var sourceChars = letters.Concat(myString.ToUpperInvariant());
 var results = from c in sourceChars
                      group c by c into g
                      where char.IsLetter(g.Key)
                      orderby g.Key
                      select new { Char = g.Key, Count = g.Count() - 1 };

 foreach (var result in results)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("There are {0} {1}'s.", result.Count, result.Char);
 }
```

This will return you a class of how many times each letter appears in `myString`

Comment: Thanks for answer but the compiler is not detecting ".ToUpperInvariant()" function

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas - Its a legitimate function. The docs [are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx). Double check to make sure you aren't misspelling it. If it still doesn't work, replace it with `ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: What's the first line for?

Comment: @GertArnold - It selects only letters. OP said he did not want to select whitespace and I assumed he wouldn't want numbers or punctuation either. So I added that line to filter it to only letters.

Comment: I only adds 26 characters to the string. The filter is in `char.IsLetter`.